# Snap apps Not showing in Ubuntu software centre

Tags: software-center, snap

I had unistalled snap from Ubuntu 18.04 after it created loop partitions. But after reinstalling it, snap apps are not showing up in ubuntu software centre as it does not get enabled snap support. Please help me to link the ubuntu software centre to snap store.

Answer (score 12):

You're probably missing the snap plugin. This can be fixed by re-installing it.

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

It's worth noting that if you remove core components, you can re-instate everything with this one command:-

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

This ensures that the 'task' named `ubuntu-desktop` gets installed, which pulls in all the things that may have been removed.

Comment: I have this same issue on 18.04. I have `gnome-software-plugin-snap` installed, but I cannot see my own app there. It can still be installed in the CLI from stable - no problems there. Should the application be automatically available in the software center, too?