# Proprietary software not displayed in software-center Ubuntu16.06

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I'm currently using two system. One is a VM with Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on it, and the other one is a real machine with the same OS.

I would like to download and install pycharm **by the software center**. On the VM i could the see pycharm page with the download button. Everything works fine.

But on my real machine I can't see any porietary software. Only free soft are displayed in the software-center.

What should I do to see all the proprietary software which are displayed on my VM on the software-center of my real machine?

Comment: Compare the settings in `Settings -> Software & Updates` and make sure that they are the same for both installations.

Comment: The settings are similar. Only one parameter in "other software" is different. It's a reference to CUDA repo. After disabeling this parameter and reboting my computer, nothing changed into the software center.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Pycharm that you are looking for is a `snap` app.  You might want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043516/snap-apps-not-showing-in-ubuntu-software-centre

Comment: You are right, it seems like that snaps apps aren't displayed in my software center. But the cmd "sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap" do not work for ubuntu 16.04 (reference to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043516/snap-apps-not-showing-in-ubuntu-software-centre).

Comment: After "sudo apt-get remove gnome-software" and "sudo apt-get install gnome-software" nothing changed.
The version of gnome-software are the same on my VM and my real machine.

Comment: It is probably a bug in the installation.  You can file a bug report for it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: This bug could be related to my network. On my real machine i'm using a proxy which seems blocking snap cmd. _"error cannot install "hello-world" : Post https://api/snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: proxyconnect tcp: tls: oversized record received with lenght 20527"_
On my VM i'm using a network without proxy.